# Wrapping element in choose construction. How to improve?

Tags: xslt, optimization

Is there any way to optimize this code.

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="val1 = val2">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <div>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

I do not like having to write twice the same `<xsl:apply-templates select="node"/>`.

---

**Update:**

The idea is that depending on the result of comparison to do **one** of two things:

1. Just print some information (which we obtain after applying the template `<xsl:apply-templates select="node"/>`).
2. Print **the same** information, but in advance "**wrapping**" it in the container (`div` for example).

Comment: A very good question again (+1)! See my answer for the wanted short solution, which issues `<xsl:apply-templates>` only once. :)

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, I, as always, poorly set task. See update in question.

Comment: I don't see any update!   ???

Comment: @Dimitre Novatchev, done at last.

Comment: I updated my answer accordinglt. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node">
  <xsl:sort select="not(val1 = val2)"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

**Here is a complete example. This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <t>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node">
          <xsl:sort select="not(val1 = val2)"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
  </t>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="node[not(val1 = val2)]">
  <div>
     <node>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
     </node>
  </div>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<t>
  <node>
    <val1>1</val1>
    <val2>2</val2>
  </node>
  <node>
    <val1>3</val1>
    <val2>3</val2>
  </node>
</t>
```

produces the wanted, correct result:

```
<t>
   <node>
      <val1>3</val1>
      <val2>3</val2>
   </node>
   <div>
      <node>
         <val1>1</val1>
         <val2>2</val2>
      </node>
   </div>
</t>
```

**Explanation of the solution**:

Whenever an `<xsl:apply-templates>` has an `<xsl:sort>` child, the nodes that are selected are sorted according the data provided in the `<xsl:sort>` child(ren) and the results of applying templates on each selected node appear in the output in that (sort) order -- not in document order.

In the transformation above we have:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="node"> 
  <xsl:sort select="not(val1 = val2)"/> 
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

This means that the results of applying templates to the elements named `node` for which it is true that `val1=val2` will appear before the results of applying templates to the elements named `node` for which `val1=val2` is not true. This is because `false` sorts before `true`.

If this explanation is not clear, the reader is directed to read more about [**`<xsl:sort>`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116#element-sort).

Comment: I do not understand what's going on here sorting.

Answer (score 0):

This is hardy possible for that simple example, but if the amount of the wrapping code and the duplicate code are worth bothering, you have two options:

1. introduce a chain of templates with different modes:

   ```
   <!-- instead of choose -->
   <xsl:apply-template match="." mode="container" />
   ...
   <xsl:template match="container" mode="container">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="dup-group"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="container[val1=val2]" mode="container">
       <div>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="dup-group"/>
       </div>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="container" mode="dup-group">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node"/>
       <!-- other duplicate code -->
       ...
   </xsl:template>
   ```
2. move a part of code into a separate imported stylesheet and override the template rule in the current stylesheet:

   ```
   <xsl:template match="container[val1=val2]">
       <div>
           <xsl:apply-imports />
       </div>
   </xsl:template>
   ```

Answer (score -1):

The xslt you are posting here is not very optimizable. If the code that you don't want to duplicate would be more than two lines, you could optimize by creating a named template and calling that instead. In this example it really doesn't make much sense, but you'll get the idea:

```
<xsl:when test="val1=val2">
  <xsl:call-template name="optimized"/>
</xsl:when>
<xsl:otherwise>
  <div>
    <xsl:call-template name="optimized"/>
  </div>
</xsl:otherwise>
```

And the template:

```
<xsl:template name="optimized">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node"/>
</xsl:template>
```

The called template is in the same context as the calling code, so you can just copy the code you don't want to duplicate to the named template.